# jquery calls to Cakephp 3 Controller

Tags: jquery, cakephp

perhaps someone can help me find my mistake.

In Cakephp I would like to use the jquery autocomplete, and when user selects a value check with the Controller if a new Value should be stored in Database or not.

here is the code for view

```
<?php    
echo $this->Form->input('Name',  array(
    'label' => 'Anbieter', 
    'empty' => true,
    'required' => 'required',
    'templates' => array(
        'inputContainer' => '{{content}}',
    ),
    'class' => 'select anbieter',
    'id' => 'Anbieter'
));
```

and script

```
<script>
jQuery('#Anbieter').autocomplete({
    source:'<?php echo Cake\Routing\Router::url(array('controller' => 'Anbieter', 'action' => 'getAll')); ?>',
    minLength: 0,
    autoFill: false,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo Cake\Routing\Router::url(array('controller' => 'Anbieter', 'action' => 'addCreate')); ?>',
            success: function(event, ui){
                console.log(ui);
            },
            error: function(event, ui){
                console.log(ui);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

in Controller I have this

```
public function add()
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('other');
    $anbieter = $this->Anbieter->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $anbieter = $this->Anbieter->patchEntity($anbieter, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Anbieter->save($anbieter)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The anbieter has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The anbieter could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('anbieter'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['anbieter']);
}

public function addCreate()
{
    if($this->request->is('ajax')){
        // do nothing for now
    }

}
```

this is just dummy code, so please dont be picky about it ;)

my Problem is, if I use code above, I'll get a Internal Server Error, but if I Change

```
url: '<?php echo Cake\Routing\Router::url(array('controller' => 'Anbieter', 'action' => 'addCreate')); ?>'
```

to

```
url: '<?php echo Cake\Routing\Router::url(array('controller' => 'Anbieter', 'action' => 'add')); ?>',
```

all works fine...
but this is not what I want, so what am I missing?

thanks a lot in advanced

l.b.

edit:
error
    toolbar.js:90 GET http://localhost/anbieter/add-create 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP! Also show/describe the proper context, ie show/highlight the code that actually triggers the error, and please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rule number 2 of ajax: return something from the ajaxed page

```
 if($this->request->is('ajax')){
        return json_encode(['message'=>'Sucess'])
    }
```

Comment: hey thanks, tried that and a lot of different stuff... still not working, funny enough, even if I copy the stuff from add to addCreate it wont work, I think I'm missing something somewhere else. Is there anywhere to prototype functions in CakePhp?

Comment: Controller actions can only return `\Cake\Network\Response` instances or `null`.

Comment: is the cakephp route correct, how is your xhr request body like?

Comment: if i remember correctly cakephp returns a default view try using `$this->autoRender = false;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set something to view variables in your controller action:

```
$this->set('results',  ['foo' => 'bar']));
$this->set('_serialize', 'results');
```

Comment: as I mentioned below, even if I c/p the code from add to addCreate (with or without autoRender = false) It won't work.

Comment: Could you post your error you received and error.log

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot you all.

it seems to have been a Problem with the older CakePHP (3.2.?)

I now updated to 3.3.9 and all works fine.